# Referencing a non existing variable in jsp file

Tags: jsp, el

What is the expected behaviour when testing a non-existing variable in a jsp file
for Java 1.4.2 and Tomcat 5.0?

for example:

```
<c:when test="${testVariable ne 'test'}">
    1
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
    2
</c:otherwise>
```

will this code display `1`, `2` or some kind of exception on the site, given that the testVariable doesn't exist?

Comment: Shouldn't be to hard to test on your installation should it?

Comment: You're right, sorry. I was hoping someone would know how it works without having to install whole envrioment to do small check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non existing variable will just be treated as `null`.